# Operational State Down on QLogic 20 Port 8Gb Intelligent Pass-thru Switch Module

Tags: ibm, qlogic

I have an IBM blade center with 13 HS22 (mix of 4Gb & 8Gb Qlogic HBAs) servers and duel 4Gb brocade fiber SAN switch.
I am replacing both brocade SAN switch with QLogic 8Gb 20 Ports, Intelligent Pass-thru Module(44X1905).
After replacing the switch, all the internal ports status is showing "Downed". How can i activate these ports?

```
QLOGIC8GbT: USERID> SHOW PORT

          Admin       Operational  Login       Config Running     Link     Link
  Port    State       State        Status      Type   Type        State    Speed
  ----    -----       -----------  ------      ------ -------     -----    -----
  Ext1:0  Online      Online       LoggedIn    TF     TF          Active   8Gb/s
  Ext2:15 Online      Offline      NotLoggedIn TF     TF          Inactive Auto
  Ext3:16 Online      Offline      NotLoggedIn TF     TF          Inactive Auto
  Ext4:17 Online      Offline      NotLoggedIn TF     TF          Inactive Auto
  Ext5:18 Online      Offline      NotLoggedIn TF     TF          Inactive Auto
  Ext6:19 Online      Offline      NotLoggedIn TF     TF          Inactive Auto

  Bay1    Online      Downed       NotLoggedIn TH     TH(iso)     Inactive Auto
  Bay2    Online      Downed       NotLoggedIn TH     TH(iso)     Inactive Auto
  Bay3    Online      Offline      NotLoggedIn TH     TH          Inactive Auto
  Bay4    Online      Downed       NotLoggedIn TH     TH(iso)     Inactive Auto
  Bay5    Online      Downed       NotLoggedIn TH     TH(iso)     Inactive Auto
  Bay6    Online      Downed       NotLoggedIn TH     TH(iso)     Inactive Auto
  Bay7    Online      Downed       NotLoggedIn TH     TH(iso)     Inactive Auto
  Bay8    Online      Downed       NotLoggedIn TH     TH(iso)     Inactive Auto
  Bay9    Online      Downed       NotLoggedIn TH     TH(iso)     Inactive Auto
  Bay10   Online      Downed       NotLoggedIn TH     TH(iso)     Inactive Auto
  Bay11   Online      Downed       NotLoggedIn TH     TH(iso)     Inactive Auto
  Bay12   Online      Downed       NotLoggedIn TH     TH(iso)     Inactive Auto
  Bay13   Online      Offline      NotLoggedIn TH     TH          Inactive Auto
  Bay14   Online      Downed       NotLoggedIn TH     TH(iso)     Inactive Auto

QLOGIC8GbT: USERID> show port 14

  Port Number: 14
  ------------
  ActiveTFPortMap    None
  AdminState         Online
  AsicNumber         0
  AsicPort           10
  ConfigType         TH
  DownstreamISL      False
  EpConnState        None
  EpIsoReason        MappedPortOffline
  LinkSpeed          Auto
  LinkState          Inactive
  LoginStatus        NotLoggedIn
  MaxCredit          16
  MediaPartNumber
  MediaRevision
  MediaSpeeds        2, 4, 8Gb/s
  MediaType          NotApplicable
  MediaVendor
  MediaVendorID
  OperationalState   Downed
  PerfTuningMode     Normal
  PortWWN            20:0e:00:c0:dd:23:e8:ec
  POSTFaultCode      00000000
  POSTStatus         Passed
  RunningType        TH
  SupportedSpeeds    2, 4, 8Gb/s
  SymbolicName       Port14
  SyncStatus         SyncLost
  TestFaultCode      00000000
  TestStatus         NeverRun
  UpstreamISL        False
  XmitterEnabled     False

                     Port Statistics

  ALInit             0                   LIP_F8_F7          0
  ALInitError        0                   LinkFailures       0
  BadFrames          0                   Login              0
  BBCR_FrameFailures 0                   Logout             0
  BBCR_RRDYFailures  0                   LongFramesIn       0
  Class2FramesIn     0                   LoopTimeouts       0
  Class2FramesOut    0                   LossOfSync         0
  Class2WordsIn      0                   LostFrames         0
  Class2WordsOut     0                   LostRRDYs          0
  Class3FramesIn     6                   PrimSeqErrors      0
  Class3FramesOut    0                   RxLinkResets       3
  Class3Toss         0                   RxOfflineSeq       3
  Class3WordsIn      216                 ShortFramesIn      0
  Class3WordsOut     0                   TotalErrors        2724
  DecodeErrors       2724                TotalLinkResets    6
  EpConnects         0                   TotalLIPsRecvd     0
  FBusy              0                   TotalLIPsXmitd     0
  FlowErrors         0                   TotalOfflineSeq    25
  FReject            0                   TotalRxFrames      6
  InvalidCRC         0                   TotalRxWords       216
  InvalidDestAddr    0                   TotalTxFrames      0
  LIP_AL_PD_AL_PS    0                   TotalTxWords       0
  LIP_F7_AL_PS       0                   TxLinkResets       3
  LIP_F7_F7          0                   TxOfflineSeq       22
  LIP_F8_AL_PS       0
```

Answer (score 0):

port can be down for several reasons.

1. incompatible connectors.
2. phy conn issues.
3. or unable to login to SAN sw.
   is NPIV active/UP on qlogic port? if it is down you will have to purchase the extra license/feature.